# Get receipt confirmation from the listener in JMS

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I'm using Spring JMS and ActiveMQ to send message from a sender to multiple listeners using JMS topic (publish/subscribe). So far all listeners can receive message from the sender. But I want to add a functionality that when a particular listener, say listener1, gets the message, listener1 will send a receipt confirmation to the sender. I followed the comment in  [my old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059056/how-to-know-if-a-listener-gets-the-message-in-jms) and created a `TemporaryQueue` in the sender and used ReplyTo in the sender and receiver to get the confirmation message from the listener to the sender.

My sender class is:

```
public class CustomerStatusSender {
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    private Topic topic;

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }
    
    public void setTopic(Topic topic) {
        this.topic = topic;
    }
    
    public void simpleSend(final String customerStatusMessage) {
        jmsTemplate.send(topic, new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("hello world");
                message.setStringProperty("content", customerStatusMessage);
                message.setIntProperty("count", 10);
                //send acknowledge request to a listener via a tempQueue
                Destination tempQueue = session.createTemporaryQueue();
                message.setJMSCorrelationID("replyMessage");
                message.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue);
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The sender creates a `TemporaryQueue` for the listener to send back the confirmation message. Then in one of the listeners, I have the following code to send the confirmation message back to the sender:

```
public class CustomerStatusListener implements SessionAwareMessageListener<Message> {
    public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Subscriber 1 got you! The message is: "
                        + message.getStringProperty("content"));
                //create a receipt confirmation message and send it back to the sender
                Message response = session.createMessage();
                response.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSCorrelationID());
                response.setBooleanProperty("Ack", true);
                TemporaryQueue tempQueue = (TemporaryQueue) message.getJMSReplyTo();
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(tempQueue);
                producer.send(tempQueue, response);
            } catch (JMSException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Message must be of type TextMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

However, I found that the following line in the Listener class throws an error:

```
TemporaryQueue tempQueue = (TemporaryQueue) message.getJMSReplyTo();
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(tempQueue);
```

The exception error says:

```
The destination temp-queue://ID:xyz-1385491-1:2:1 does not exist.
```

So what's wrong here? I assume that `tempQueue` created by the sender is available for the listener in the same JMS session. Why the `tempQueue` object after calling `message.getJMSReplyTo()` does not return a valid `TemporaryQueue`?

The other question is: How do I receive the confirmation message in the sender? Should I implements `MessageListener` interface in the sender in order to receive the confirmation from the listener? Or should I just call `receive()` method to receive it synchronously?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I'd check that the temp queue really gets created. Go to [ActiveMQ web console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html) and see what's going on.

Comment: I went to the ActiveMQ web admin web console and checked it. I didn't find any items under the `Queue` column. Should `TemporaryQueue` belong to `Queue` in ActiveMQ?

Comment: I'm not sure about queues created with createTemproraryQueue(), but named temp queues which just start with "dynamicQueues" definitely show up. Check out "Dynamically creating destinations" section of [this document](http://activemq.apache.org/jndi-support.html) - maybe it will work for your project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-jms, why not just use a [MessageListenerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-receiving-async-message-listener-adapter) as your listener? - he will take care of the replyTo stuff and your listener can be a simple POJO.

In any case, you don't need to cast it to a Tempoarary queue; it's just a destination as far as the listener is concerned.

Checkout the [MessageListenerAdapter` javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/adapter/MessageListenerAdapter.html).

Also, you need to create a consumer on the temp queue on the sending side, to receive the reply. If the sending connection is closed, the temp queue will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a separate JMS Queue to send the acknowledge message from the listener-1 to the sender. For some reason, the temporaryQueue created by ActiveMQ is not available during the JMS session.